# Calling user defined functions in php for mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, function, defined

Hi I'm trying to call several functions that I have defined in php within mysql_query. The sql query executes successfully however all the columns which should contain values from functions are left empty in the database. The sql query looks like this:

```
$sqldescription = description($e->href);
$sqlimage = image($e->href,$e->innertext);
$sqlstatus = status($e->href);
$sqlgenre = genre($e->href);
$sqlauthor = author($e->href);
$sqlrelease = release($e->href);
$sql = "INSERT INTO manga (`manga_title`, `manga_description`, `manga_thumnail`, `manga_latest_chap`, `manga_status`, `manga_genre`, `manga_author`, `manga_released_date`, `manga_added_date`, `manga_link`) VALUES 
('" . $e->innertext . "', '" . $sqldescription . "', '$sqlimage', '0', '$sqlstatus', '$sqlgenre', '$sqlauthor', '$sqlrelease', '" . date("Y-m-d") . "', '" . $e->href . "')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
```

most of the functions are pretty similar and here is what one of them looks like:

```
    function description($url){
      $descriptionhtml = new simple_html_dom();
      $descriptionhtml->load_file($url);
      foreach ($descriptionhtml->find('p.summary') as $d)
      echo $d;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: The function is wrong, you should use `return` instead of echo. And we don't know anything about the variable `$e`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you aly. so return instead of echo. Thanks so much :)

I spent over an hour on this one problem lol.